# Create Layout and test the changes on the emulator failed

Tags: android

i have the problem, that if i create a new layout and change the layout in the graphical layout for example add a button or a textfield to the layout, that the application can´t be installed on the emulated device. I get the unusable error "Failed to install *.apk on device 'emulator-5556': timeout
Launch canceled!".
If i remove the button or textfield then the emulator runs the application. I tested many things. I removed Eclipse and the Android SDK. Installed different Versions of the Eclipse Software (Classic, JAVAEE) and then installed the android SDK every time new. Nothing changed. I deleted the .android folder in my Windows Userprofile. But nothing changed.
What is wrong.

The Code of my layout:

> ```
>  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:orientation="vertical" >
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/textView1"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="Large Text"
>         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

the code of the Activity:

> ```
>     package de.androidpraxis.HelloAndroid;
>
> import android.app.Activity;
> import android.os.Bundle;
>
> public class HelloAndroidActivity extends Activity {
>     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
>     @Override
>     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.layout);
>     }
> }
> ```

i hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

greetings

edit:
I found something out. I have a project with a standard layout and an folder for land-layout. If i delete the land-layout folder with the xml files in that the application runs in the emulator. How could i do it right without deleting the other folder?

Comment: Is that the complete code of your layout? If so, your XML version is missing `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`, as well as the type of layout (ex: linearlayout)

Answer (score 0):

```
> I get the unusable error "Failed to install *.apk on device 'emulator-5556': 
> timeout Launch
```

this issue has nothing to do with your layout design.
this is a adb issue.

try executing this command from any terminal or console window
prior to installing your application

path/to/your/android-sdk/platform-tools/.adb kill-server

Comment: I tried your command and in the console Log i get the following:
[2012-03-08 12:07:58 - Device] Error during Sync: timeout.
>     [2012-03-08 12:08:03 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen(in english
> something like "An existing connection was forcibly closed by remote
> host")
>     [2012-03-08 12:08:05 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
>     [2012-03-08 12:08:07 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 2
nothing changes. The Problem is still there

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</LinearLayout>
```

You can try this new layout xml file. And, you should notice that, this file name "layout.xml" and put it in `layout folder`. But, I don't think this is a problem, because when you don't do this will see error when compile

Comment: where is the difference to mine?

Comment: You missing two thing: first is <?xml...> and second, <LinearLayout tab, maybe its your typo ?